# Почему после того, как пользователь нажимает на /remindme, ничего не происходит

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import sqlite3
import threading
import time
from telegram.ext import (Updater, ConversationHandler, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters)
import telebot
from telebot import types

TOKEN = ' '
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
bd = sqlite3.connect('remindnotes.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = bd.cursor()

with open('remind.sql', 'r') as f:
    sql = f.read()
bd.commit()

updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
disp = updater.dispatcher
current_name = None
current_date = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_keyboard(message, text='Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?'):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Добавить новую заметку')
    itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Новое напоминание')
    itembtn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Все заметки')
    itembtn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Удалить заметку')
    itembtn5 = types.KeyboardButton('Удалить все заметки')
    itembtn6 = types.KeyboardButton('Другое')
    itembtn7 = types.KeyboardButton('Пока все!')
    keyboard.add(itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3)
    keyboard.add(itembtn4, itembtn5, itembtn6, itembtn7)

    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=text, reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, callback_worker)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.text == 'Добавить новую заметку':
        msg = bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'Давайте добавим дело! Пришлите его в наш чат..')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, add_plan)
    elif call.text == 'Все заметки':
        try:
            show_plans(call)
        except:
            bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'Здесь пусто.. Можно отдыхать:))')
            send_keyboard(call, 'Чем еще могу помочь?')
    elif call.text == 'Новое напоминание':
        try:
            create_new(call)
        except:
            bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'Может нужна помощь?')
            send_keyboard(call, 'Чем еще могу помочь?')
    elif call.text == 'Удалить заметку':
        try:
            delete_one_plan(call)
        except:
            bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'Здесь пусто.. Можно отдыхать:))')
            send_keyboard(call, 'Чем еще могу помочь?')
    elif call.text == 'Удалить все заметки':
        try:
            delete_all_plans(call)
        except:
            bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'Здесь пусто.. Можно отдыхать:))')
            send_keyboard(call, 'Чем еще могу помочь?')

    elif call.text == 'Другое':
        bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'Пока я больше ничего не умею(')
        send_keyboard(call, 'Чем еще могу помочь?')
    elif call.text == 'Пока все!':
        bot.send_message(call.chat.id, 'Хорошего дня! Когда захотите продолжить - нажмите /start ')
def add_plan(msg):
    with sqlite3.connect('remindnotes.db') as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO planner (user_id, plan) VALUES (?, ?)', (msg.from_user.id, msg.text))
        con.commit()
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Запомню!')
    send_keyboard(msg, 'Чем еще могу помочь?')
def delete_one_plan(msg):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    with sqlite3.connect('remindnotes.db') as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT plan FROM planner WHERE user_id=={}'.format(msg.from_user.id))
        tasks = cursor.fetchall()
        for value in tasks:
            markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(value[0]))
        msg = bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, text = 'Выберите одно дело из списка', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, delete_one_plan_1)
def delete_one_plan_1(msg):
    with sqlite3.connect('remindnotes.db') as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM planner WHERE user_id==? AND plan==?', (msg.from_user.id, msg.text))
        bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Ура, минус одна задача!')
        send_keyboard(msg, 'Чем еще могу помочь?')
def delete_all_plans(msg):
    with sqlite3.connect('remindnotes.db') as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute('DELETE FROM planner WHERE user_id=={}'.format(msg.from_user.id))
        con.commit()
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Все дела удалены, хорошего отдыха!')
    send_keyboard(msg, 'Могу ли я еще чем то помочь?')
def get_plans_string(tasks):
    tasks_str = []
    for val in list(enumerate(tasks)):
        tasks_str.append(str(val[0] + 1) + ') ' +val[1][0] + '\n' )
    return ''.join(tasks_str)
def show_plans(msg):
    with sqlite3.connect('remindnotes.db') as con:
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT plan FROM planner WHERE user_id=={}'.format(msg.from_user.id))
        tasks = get_plans_string(cursor.fetchall())
        bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, tasks)
        send_keyboard(msg, 'Чем еще могу помочь?')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['new'])
def create_new(update):
    bot.send_message(update.chat.id, 'Нажми /remindme для добавления задачи')

def new_reminder(update):
    update.message.reply_text('Введите название напоминания')
    return 1
def get_name(update):
    global current_name
    update.message.reply_text('Напиши дату в формате ГОД-МЕСЯЦ-ДЕНЬ')
    return 2

def get_date(update):
    global current_date
    global cursor
    current_date = update.message.text
    user_id = update.message.chat_id
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?', (user_id,))
    if not cursor.fetchone():
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user (id) VALUES (?)', (user_id,))
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO remind_me (user_id, note, date, reminded) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                   (user_id, current_name, current_date, 0))
    bd.commit()
    msg.message.reply_text('Я напомню тебе!')
    return ConversationHandler.END

def cancel():
    pass

def do_reminders():
    while True:
        # today = dt.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM remind_me WHERE strftime("%d", date) = strftime("%d", "now")' 
                       'AND strftime("%m", "now") AND reminded = 0')
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            row_id = row[0]
            note = row[2]
            user_id = row[4]
            updater.bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text =f'Время для выполнения задачи {note}!')
            cursor.execute('UPDATE remind_me SET reminded = 1 WHERE id = ?', (row_id,))
            bd.commit()
        time.sleep(10)

conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('remindme', new_reminder)],
    states = {
        1: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_name)],
        2: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_date)]
    },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
)


threading.Thread(target=do_reminders).start()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: что то в вашем коде не видно обработчика для команды `/remindme`